# Applications for vector spaces without inner product.

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question, applications

Vector spaces may not be equipped with an inner product (for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247425/is-there-a-vector-space-that-cannot-be-an-inner-product-space)). Mathematically, one can study such spaces in its own right, but I was just wondering: is there a scientific application to such spaces? For instance I will try to imagine a physical system that can be described with a vector space without an inner product but I can't come up with an easy example.

My guess is that maybe for some stochastic equations describing a system this could be achieved, but I'm not sure. I appreciate if example in Physics could be provided, but other fields (e.g. Computer Science) are welcome.

Comment: Yes, the latter you said.

Answer (score 3):

As you point out, finite fields may not be equipped with an inner product. But one may have vector spaces over such finite fields.
See here for more answers: [Explicit example of a vector space over a finite field, and linear transformation of vector spaces over different fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588323/explicit-example-of-a-vector-space-over-a-finite-field-and-linear-transformatio)

For a practical application, consider some sequence of Random Variables $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$ that may take only discrete values ($X\in K$) where $K$ is a some finite field (or cartesian product of finite fields). Then one may want to model evolution of X over such a field, for which the vector space formulation may be useful.

You may want to look up elliptic curve cryptography for some concrete examples where finite fields are used in CS.